# `<mspace linebreak="newline" />` not working with explorer accessibility

Tags: mathjax, mathml

When the accessibility explorer is activated, MathML line break, `<mspace linebreak="newline" />`, won't work.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Open https://jsbin.com/sajujukiwe/1/edit?html,js,output
2. Check how math expression  is displayed by making accessibility `explorer` property to `false` and `true`.

When `explorer` is set to false there will be a line break which is what I want but I also want the accessibility feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround here, https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/2496#issuecomment-675626155.

> The issue turns out to be in the a11y extension that handles the
> collapsible elements in the math. When the collapsing is in the
> content for the top-level  element, the MathML tree is not
> rebuilt quite right, and that disables the line-breaking. I have made
> a fix in the a11y repository, and it will be included in the next
> release of v2. In the meantime, you can use
>
> ```
>   <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
>   (function () {
>     var V = MathJax.version.split(/\./);
>     if (V[0] === "2" && (parseInt(V[1]) < 7 || (V[1] === "7" && parseInt(V[2]) <= 8))) {
>       MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("Collapsible Ready", function () {
>         var Collapsible = MathJax.Extension.collapsible;
>         Collapsible._MakeAction = Collapsible.MakeAction;
>         Collapsible.MakeAction = function (collapse, mml) {
>           if (mml.type !== 'math') return this._MakeAction(collapse, mml);
>           var mrow = mml.data[0]; mml.data = mrow.data; mrow.data = [];
>           var maction = this._MakeAction(collapse, mml);
>           mrow.data = mml.data; mml.data = [mrow];
>           return maction;
>         };
>       });
>     }
>   })();
>   </script>
> ```
>
> just before the script that loads MathJax.js itself in order to fix
> the issue until the new version is available. This checks the version
> number, so the patch will only affect version 2.7.8 and below.